# Add stringgrid column at runtime

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10-seattle

I have found many solutions online but they aren't working becaue the `StringGrid1.ColumnCount` peoperty is read only. I am using Delphi 10 Seattle.

I have a StringGrid1 and I need to add columns at runtime. To be specific I have to add columns according to the size of a TList. In particular:

```
var a: TList<double>;
begin

 //fill the TList...

 for i := 0 to a.Count - 1 do
  begin
   StringGrid1.AddColumn(); //how can I do this?
  end;

end;
```

I find this very easy on Lazarus (but it has FPC of course) but on Delphi I really don't know what to do. I am working on Firemonkey.

Comment: "*the `StringGrid1.ColCount` property is read only*" - that is only true in FireMonkey. The `ColCount` property is read/write in VCL. Also, in FMX, there is no `ColCount` property, it is actually named `ColumnCount` instead. Next time, please indicate which framework you are using.

Comment: Difficult to know what you are talking about

Comment: I did't explain very well the question, but I simply need to add a column (TStringColums) in a TStringGrid.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the grid's [`AddObject()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Types.TFmxObject.AddObject) or [`InsertObject()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Types.TFmxObject.InsertObject) method to add an object instance of the desired [`TColumn`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Grid.TColumn)-derived class, like [`TStringColumn`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Grid.TColumn).  The column object will get added to the grid's [`Columns`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Grid.TCustomGrid.Columns) array.  The [`ColumnCount`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Grid.TCustomGrid.ColumnCount) property simply returns the number of columns in the array, that is why it is read-only.

Comment: StringGrid1.AddObject(TStringColumn.Create(StringGrid1));